# How to convert GB2312 (chinese) characters in UTF-8 inside Weblogic 12?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, weblogic, gb2312

We have pages that´re using simplified Chinese (GB2312) in the HTML form. When we submit the form with 3 Chinese characters in a text field, we receive 6 others characters (that aren't in Chinese) in the server (Weblogic 12). Then we save these 6 characters in the database, and when get it back to the screen the Chinese character is back. Work´s fine!

But, when we receive the 6 characters (that aren't Chinese) in the server, we would need to call a web service that only receive UTF-8 characters.How can I convert the original 3 Chinese (GB2312, that´re in the HTML page) characters in UTF-8?

I don´t know if the characters will be show in the forum, but I´ll try:

In the HTML form: 陈玉珍

Received in the Weblogic server: ³ÂÓñÕä

Answer (score 0):

http://www.521yy.com/tools/GB2312-UTF8.html

Since this is a Chinese website. Let me explain a little bit in English

Copy your Chinese character into the black form, and click the left button on the bottom, it should convert to UTF-8 character. And the right bottom is reset. Hope it helps.